# CocoaPods private pod using private pod

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoapods

I'm new using cocoapods and have recently created a private cocoapods repo (integrated with git…)

I have a private pod library1 using another private pod library2.

How can I do that with the podspec files ?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#dependency shows how to add a dependency for another pod. In your case, you will add pod library2 as a dependency for pod library1, in pod library1's pod spec file

Comment: I have just done what you describe here.

The library2 is in fact a lib downloaded from CocoaPods, modified and added to our private CocoaPods repository.

The problem is that referencing library2 like spec.dependency = "library2" in the library1.podspec will use the CocoaPods repository version instead of the one in our private repository.

How can I specify the private repository ?

Comment: Since we use only one private repo at work I have no experience about managing two such Pod Repositories, still here are some suggestions that you can try:

1. Make sure that both private repositories are added with pod repo add ... command
2. Open up terminal and go to ~/.cocoapods/repos and check that you have master, library1 and library2 folders in there, if not, there's something wrong.
3. Make sure that the names of your private repo's are not publicly used.
4. If all above fails, consider having one big project and separate things using subspecs (this is what we do)

Comment: I use only two repositories : the CocoaPods default one and our private one. The library2 had been downloaded from the CocoaPods server repository and added to our private repository. So CocoaPods does not the private one but the "public" one…